# Follow an emitted signal to its connected slot(s)?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, signals-slots

I understand that a Qt signal is put onto the event queue, and then the connected slots are called later when the event loop sees it.  So it doesn't make sense to "step into" it when debugging.  But I really do want to see, in a large enough app that I can't keep all of it in mind at once, where the control flow ends up.

So is there a way to find the slot(s) that are connected to a signal, either potentially based on `connect(...);` calls or actually at the moment when debugging?

---

In Qt Creator 3.5.1 (Based on Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 5.2.1 20151129, 64 bit)):

1. `Ctrl+Shift+U` (find usages) only returns `emit signal();` in the source and `void signal();` in the header.

   - It'd be really nice if it would also return `connect(..., SIGNAL(signal()), ..., SLOT(slot()));` so I could then `F2` (go to definition) on `slot()` and put a `breakpoint` in it.
2. A plaintext search returns a bunch of unrelated signals with the same name in other classes, so that's not really helpful either.

Comment: * Qt signal is put onto the event queue -- for Queued connection only. Auto connection implies `connect` decides whether or not it will be Queued (if sender and recipient are on different threads) and Direct leads to function being called from this stack now.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I knew that too, but even for Direct, "stepping into" the `emit ...` line doesn't actually follow it.  Identical behavior to "stepping over".  I need something that works for Queued and Direct both, and tells me where the slot(s) are that (could) end up getting called, either immediately or when an event loop gets around to it.

Comment: *"It'd be really nice if it would also return `connect(..., SIGNAL(signal()), ..., SLOT(slot()));` so I could then F2 (go to definition) on `slot()` and put a breakpoint in it"* << It can detect these usages when using [the new connect syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Comment: @AaronD try putting a breakpoint in the slot function for the direct connection to see whether or not that is just a function call.

Comment: @Mike Oh!  Wow, how did I miss that?  Maybe because Google returned some old documentation as the top results and I didn't notice?  Anyway, I changed all 227 usages, and it works!  Thank you!  Make that an answer, and I'll probably end up accepting it.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Yes, that's how I know they're direct.  The stack trace shows the emitting function, then some inaccessible Meta work, then the slot function.  If "stepping into" would follow that, it'd be wonderful, but it doesn't.

Comment: We often cannot see the source code while tracing the stack, no symbols to connect to source code or no mapping to actual source code files.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Yet I can double-click on an entry and go directly to the corresponding source.  (except for precompiled system-internals; then it gives me a disassembly listing)  That's very useful!  You're saying that what I'm actually already doing is impossible?

Comment: @AlexanderVX Hint: try `F5` instead of `Ctrl+R`, and use a Debug build instead of Release.

Comment: Of course @AaronD we can always apply some effort and see the actual file if symbols and the source code available. I meant debug. Not sure why it is so interesting: on the stack is for direct signal connection, all that matters here.

Comment: Unrelated, but since you're using Qt5 you should be using the [new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) in your `connect()` calls.

Comment: BTW, Release build does not prevent from having symbols for devs and we can still find and see the source code line for the crash etc.

Comment: Actually, @MrEricSir, you're exactly on-topic.  Mike beat you to it a few hours ago, but if either one of you wants to make an answer out of it, I'll accept it.  It's AlexanderVX that seems to be flying off-topic.  I'm keeping up with him anyway in case he's onto something that I haven't figured out yet, but so far I'm coming up empty.  (the apparent reversal of his position just now doesn't help his credibility)

Comment: @AaronD If you connect your signal & slot like this: `connect(widget, &QWidget::destroyed, this, &MainWindow::widgetDestroy);`  find usage will show it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) :

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged,receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);
```

With this connection you can find usage and Qt will find connection line.

[image: sample code image]